# Casting the value created in LINQ object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, casting

I'm getting my list selected items on to `DataGrid` like this.

```
using (REntities RAEntity = new REntities())
{
    var all = RAEntity.TBLM_PRODUCT.ToList<DataControllers.TBLM_PRODUCT>();
    var selectionList = all.Where(x => x.PRODUCT_PROGROUP == "GL").Select(p => new { p.PRODUCT_DESC, p.PRODUCT_SPRICE }).ToList();

    bs.DataSource = selectionList;
    dg.DataSource = bs;
}
```

And on `DataGridView` selection, in a button click I get value to my `TextBox` in other form like this.

```
if (window.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{    
    selectedProduct = (DataControllers.TBLM_PRODUCT)bs.Current;
    txtServiceType.Text = selectedProduct.PRODUCT_DESC.ToString();
```

My selected product is declared like this:

```
public partial class TBLM_PRODUCT
{           
    public string PRODUCT_CODE { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_DESC { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_ISBN { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_SUPPLIER { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_PROGROUP { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> PRODUCT_SPRICE { get; set; }
}

private TBLM_PRODUCT selectedProduct;
```

When I try to get data to the `TextBox` of other form it displays an invalid casting error like this:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]' to type ' TBLM_PRODUCT'.

How to overcome this? how can I cast when I'm passing the data to the object or how to get the data to the next form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this `Select(p => new { p.PRODUCT_DESC, p.PRODUCT_SPRICE })` you are actually returning a List of [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) instead of a list of `TBLM_PRODUCT`. Change your code to this:

```
p => new TBLM_PRODUCT {PRODUCT_DESC = p.PRODUCT_DESC, PRODUCT_SPRICE = p.PRODUCT_SPRICE }
```

And if you still get error probably it is because you cannot project onto a mapped entity then you need to create a DTO class with needed properties from the `TBLM_PRODUCT` entity, something like this:

```
public class TBLM_PRODUCTDTO
{
    public string PRODUCT_DESC { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> PRODUCT_SPRICE { get; set; }
    //Other Properties
}
```

And then use this DTO like this:

```
p => new TBLM_PRODUCTDTO {PRODUCT_DESC = p.PRODUCT_DESC, PRODUCT_SPRICE = p.PRODUCT_SPRICE }
```

And:

```
private TBLM_PRODUCTDTO selectedProduct;
selectedProduct = (TBLM_PRODUCTDTO) bs.Current;
```

Comment: I'm really sorry to ask you again, can you show a code example how the select has to be done?

Comment: @chathwind See my edited answer. Try to replace your code with this `p => new TBLM_PRODUCT {PRODUCT_DESC = p.PRODUCT_DESC, PRODUCT_SPRICE = p.PRODUCT_SPRICE } ` and if it didn't work try the DTO version.

Comment: one more problem arise, how to show only those two columns in the datagrid

Comment: @chathwind If you are seeing the unwanted null columns in your DataGrid, You can use the DTO version because it just contains the needed columns. As an alternative, based on what type is your project (WPF, ASP.NET,...) you can use set the `AutoGeneratedColumns` to false in your `DataGrid` and customize your `DataGrid`

Comment: @chathwind Use DTO like this: `p => new TBLM_PRODUCTDTO {PRODUCT_DESC = p.PRODUCT_DESC, PRODUCT_SPRICE = p.PRODUCT_SPRICE } ` and `selectedProduct = (TBLM_PRODUCTDTO )bs.Current;`